# Google Maps API OVER_QUERY_LIMIT 10 Destinations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been researching this all day and still haven't come across a solution that works. I'm using the Google Maps Distance Matrix Service with 1 origin and 14 destinations. I modified the sample code from Google (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/distance-matrix) and just added more destinations to test it out. With anything over 10 destinations, the OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error occurs and mis-places a marker.

From the usage limits I found (100 elements per 10 seconds), I shouldn't be hitting the limit at all. I have also tried inserting my API Key in this line, to no avail:

```
 src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Code changes to the sample code from Google:

```
var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(45.465422,9.185924);
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(41.385064,2.173403);
var destinationC = new google.maps.LatLng(40.416775,-3.70379);
var destinationD = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507351,-0.127758);
var destinationE = new google.maps.LatLng(48.856614,2.352222);
var destinationF = new google.maps.LatLng(41.902784,12.496366);
var destinationG = new google.maps.LatLng(50.85034,4.35171);
var destinationH = new google.maps.LatLng(46.198392,6.142296);
var destinationI = new google.maps.LatLng(47.36865,8.539183);
var destinationJ = new google.maps.LatLng(53.408371,-2.991573);
var destinationK = new google.maps.LatLng(37.389092,-5.984459);
var destinationL = new google.maps.LatLng(53.349805,-6.26031);
var destinationM = new google.maps.LatLng(55.864237,-4.251806);
var destinationN = new google.maps.LatLng(51.92442,4.477733);

function calculateDistances() {
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix(
    {
      origins: [origin],
      destinations: [destinationA, destinationB,destinationC, destinationD,destinationE, destinationF,destinationG, destinationH,destinationI, destinationJ,destinationK, destinationL, destinationM, destinationN],
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
      avoidHighways: false,
      avoidTolls: false
    }, callback);
}
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Are you using the geocoder?

Comment: It works with more than 10 destinations for me.  Please provide an example that _doesn't_ work.

Comment: I am not using the geocoder (all the destinations in my file are already lat/longs).

Comment: @geocodezip thanks for the reply. I copy pasted the exact html+javascript example from google, added 4 more destinations and it started throwing the error. The only code changes I made to the file are now included in the original post.

Comment: I get a javascript error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: origin is not defined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OVER_QUERY_ERROR is coming from the geocoder, not the DistanceMatrix call.  Remove this line:

addMarker(destinations[j], true);

(you don't need the geocoder, you already have the coordinates for the markers)

working code snippet:

```js
var map;
var geocoder;
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var markersArray = [];

var origin = new google.maps.LatLng(55.930, -3.118);
var origin2 = 'Greenwich, England';
var destinationA = new google.maps.LatLng(45.465422, 9.185924);
var destinationB = new google.maps.LatLng(41.385064, 2.173403);
var destinationC = new google.maps.LatLng(40.416775, -3.70379);
var destinationD = new google.maps.LatLng(51.507351, -0.127758);
var destinationE = new google.maps.LatLng(48.856614, 2.352222);
var destinationF = new google.maps.LatLng(41.902784, 12.496366);
var destinationG = new google.maps.LatLng(50.85034, 4.35171);
var destinationH = new google.maps.LatLng(46.198392, 6.142296);
var destinationI = new google.maps.LatLng(47.36865, 8.539183);
var destinationJ = new google.maps.LatLng(53.408371, -2.991573);
var destinationK = new google.maps.LatLng(37.389092, -5.984459);
var destinationL = new google.maps.LatLng(53.349805, -6.26031);
var destinationM = new google.maps.LatLng(55.864237, -4.251806);
var destinationN = new google.maps.LatLng(51.92442, 4.477733);




var destinationIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=D|FF0000|000000';
var originIcon = 'https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chst=d_map_pin_letter&chld=O|FFFF00|000000';

function initialize() {
  var opts = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.53, 9.4),
    zoom: 10
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), opts);
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function calculateDistances() {
  deleteOverlays();
  var destinations = [destinationA, destinationB, destinationC, destinationD, destinationE, destinationF, destinationG, destinationH, destinationI, destinationJ, destinationK, destinationL, destinationM, destinationN];
  for (var i = 0; i < destinations.length; i++) {
    bounds.extend(destinations[i]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      map: map,
      position: destinations[i],
      icon: destinationIcon
    });
    markersArray.push(marker);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
  var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: [origin],
    destinations: destinations,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, callback);

}

function callback(response, status) {
  if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
    alert('Error was: ' + status);
  } else {
    var origins = response.originAddresses;
    var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;
    var outputDiv = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
    outputDiv.innerHTML = '';


    for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
      var results = response.rows[i].elements;
      addMarker(origins[i], false);
      for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
        // addMarker(destinations[j], true);
        outputDiv.innerHTML += "<b>"+j+":</b>"+origins[i] + ' to ' + destinations[j] + ': ' + results[j].distance.text + ' in ' + results[j].duration.text + '<br>';
      }
    }
  }
}

function addMarker(location, isDestination) {
  var icon;
  if (isDestination) {
    icon = destinationIcon;
  } else {
    icon = originIcon;
  }
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': location
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      bounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location,
        icon: icon
      });
      markersArray.push(marker);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

function deleteOverlays() {
  for (var i = 0; i < markersArray.length; i++) {
    markersArray[i].setMap(null);
  }
  markersArray = [];
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
}
#content-pane {
  float: right;
  width: 48%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}
#outputDiv {
  font-size: 11px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<p>
  <button type="button" onclick="calculateDistances();">Calculate distances</button>
</p>
</div>
<div id="outputDiv"></div>
</div>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes a lot more sense. I was able to integrate your edits into my code to make it work!. I'm sure you just saved me another day of researching through StackOverflow and Google API pages... Thanks again!